# using scanf in pointers to integer

Tags: c, pointers, variables, input, scanf

This program tests Whether a pointer could be used as a variable to store input data.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int *prt;
    printf("Input prt:");
    scanf("%d", prt);
    printf("What you inputed is: %d\n", *prt);
    return 0;
}
```

And the teminal log:

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Then I wrote another test:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int *p;
    int x;
    printf("Input x:");
    scanf("%d", &x);
    p = &x;
    printf("What you inputed is: %d\n", x);
    printf("What you inputed is: %d\n", *p);
    printf("The address of x: %p\n", &x);
    printf("The address p points to: %p\n", p);

    return 0;   
}
```

And the teminal log:

```
Input x:10
What you inputed is: 10
What you inputed is: 10
The address of x: 0x7ffc5f2636f4
The address p points to: 0x7ffc5f2636f4
```

It works well. So I got confused why I can not use `prt` of the first program to accept input?

Comment: A pointer has to point *to* something.

Comment: The `scanf` function expect that the pointer is actually *pointing* somewhere (valid). In your first program `prt` isn't pointing anywhere special, and dereferencing that pointer (which `scanf` does) leads to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: In the second program, the assignment `p = &x` makes the pointer `p` point to `x`.

Comment: And as a simple way to visualize pointers, take a piece of paper and draw two boxes on it. Label one box `p` and the other `x`. Now draw an arrow from `p` to `x`, so the arrow is pointing to `x`. That's basically how pointers and the assignment `p = &x` are working. To visualize the first example, draw a box and label it `prt`. Now draw an arrow away from that box to some empty bit of the paper. It shows how `prt` isn't pointing to anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your variable `prt` is a pointer to an int, but it isn't actually initialized with a valid memory address to *point to*, so trying to read into it with `scanf` invokes undefined behavior. One likely outcome is a segmentation fault, but a segmentation fault cannot be assumed to result.

Your second example works because `&x` does point to `x`, and so we can read into it.

Answer (score 3):

[`scanf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) (with %d) requires an **address of a valid `int`** (to fill with the parsed field).

This line:

```
int *prt;
```

Is declaring `prt` an a pointer to `int`, but it is not initialized and therefore does not point to any valid `int`.
The result is [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) - anything can happen including (but not necessarily) a segmentation fault.

In your 2nd case:

```
int x;
```

`x` is declared an `int` (not a pointer to `int`), and therefore `&x` is a valid address for `scanf`.

A side note:
`scanf` is returning the number of fields successfuly parsed. You should always check it (against 1 in your case) to make sure it succeeded.